# How can I bulk rename a lot of files on Ubuntu?

Tags: rename

I have a directory that contains files named in pattern as:

```
[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 01 [1080p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 02 [1080p].mkv
```

These files go up to 700.

I wanted these files to get renamed as

```
One Piece 001.mkv
One Piece 002.mkv
```

And so on. I'm new to Linux and need help figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell (not installed by default unfortunately on Ubuntu, you'd need to run `apt install zsh zsh-doc` as `root`):

```
$ autoload -Uz zmv
$ zmv -n '\[*\] (* - )(<->) \[<->p\](.mkv)' '$1${(l[3][0])2}$3'
mv -- '[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 01 [1080p].mkv' 'One Piece - 001.mkv'
mv -- '[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 02 [1080p].mkv' 'One Piece - 002.mkv'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy with the result).

Or same with the `rename` aka `file-rename` command from the `rename` package (one of several `perl`-based `rename` implementations):

```
$ rename -n 's{^\[.*\] (.* - )(\d+) \[\d+p\](\.mkv)\z}{
  sprintf "%s%03d%s", $1, $2, $3}se' \[*.mkv
rename([HorribleSubs] One Piece - 01 [1080p].mkv, One Piece - 001.mkv)
rename([HorribleSubs] One Piece - 02 [1080p].mkv, One Piece - 002.mkv)
```

Some equivalents between those two approaches:

- `*` / `.*`: matches 0 or more characters¹.
- `<->` / `\d+`: matches 1 or more ASCII decimal digits. In `zsh`, you could also use `<1-700>` to restrict the range of numbers it matches.
- `$1`, `$2`, `$3`: in the replacement expands to what was captured in the corresponding `(...)` in the pattern.
- `l[3][0]` / `printf "%03d"`: `l`eft-pads to a length of `3` with `0`'s.

---

<sup>¹ well actually in `rename` that's 0 or more *bytes*, it could very well break some characters in the middle. For that to happen here though, you'd need the file names to be encoded in a charmap such as BIG5, GBK, GB18030 as used in some parts of East Asia, that do have several characters whose encoding contains the encoding of `]`. Also note the `s` flag without which `.` wouldn't match on byte 0xa (encoding of the newline character)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your files all follow that exact pattern, you can use `rename` on Ubuntu like this:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*- (\d+).*/"One Piece " . sprintf("%.3d",$1) . ".mkv"/e' *mkv
[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 01 [1080p].mkv -> One Piece 001.mkv
[HorribleSubs] One Piece - 02 [1080p].mkv -> One Piece 002.mkv
```

If that looks right, remove the `-n` option to actually rename the files.

Comment: Note that with the `rename` variant from the `rename` package on Ubuntu, that introduces a command injection vulnerability. Try after `touch -- '--e=system("reboot")#mkv'`. You'd want to use `--` to mark the end of options (but then that doesn't work with all `rename` variants), or use `\[*mkv` as the glob to make sure none of the arguments start with `-` (or use `zmv` which has far fewer of the issues affecting `rename`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can't reproduce that on my Arch system and I don't have access to an Ubuntu one I am free to safely reboot. As far as I can tell, on my Arch at least, if a file name starts with a `--e`, it just errors out with `unrecognized option --e` but doesn't execute the system call.

Comment: there are several variants of `perl`-based renames (and versions thereof). The one from the `rename` package on Ubuntu is based on [`File::Rename`](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename). `rename 1 '--e=system"uname"#mkv'` outputs `Linux` on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Note that you can run Ubuntu directly off the installer iso (`kvm -hda ubuntu.iso`)

Comment: Ooh, nice trick! Thanks.

Comment: The one on Arch seems to be based on https://github.com/pstray/rename